# Python list in a dict in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am new to Python please dont be too aggresive if my question is stupid.
I need a list that contains dict, in this dict i have 2 keys,in first key i got simple text , at second i need to have a list of dict (also 2 keys). What i need is:

```
daysandlessons=[]

for day in schedule:
    daysandlessons.append({'day': day.text})

    for lesson in day:
        daysandlessons['lessons'].append({'lesson':lesson.text),
                                          'lessonHour':lesson.get_hour]
                                         })
```

The real code looks like this:

```
for line in tr[1:]:
    daysandlessons.append({'day': line.find('th').get_text(separator='\n')})
    for lesson in line.findAll('td'):               
        daysandlessons['lessons'].append({
                      'lesson':lesson.get_text(separator='\n'),
                      'lessonWitdth':lesson['colspan']
                                         })
```

I am trying to **scrape**/parse schedule from university site using BeautifullSoup

So i am trying to create a second key 'lessons' and append there all lessons and 'lessonsHours'.
**This code doesnt work**. Please tell me what i am doing wrong, and second how to access all values.

Example:

```
Monday = daysandlessons[0]['day']
Mondaysecondlesson = daysandlessons[0]['lessons'][1]['lesson']
```

Comment: Please provide definition of `schedule`

Comment: So your output should look like this? [{'day': day.text, 'lessons': {'lesson': lesson.text, 'lessonHour': lesson.get_hour}}]

Comment: You can also use object orientation with classes. Deep list/dict nesting structures becomes hard to maintain. Try to revise your code one month later and see if you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution , here it is:

```
daysandlessons=[]
for day in schedule:
    temp=[]
    for lesson in day:
        temp.append({'lesson':lesson.get_text(),'hour':lesson.get_hour()})
        
    daysandlessons.append({'day':day.get_text(),'lessons':temp})
```